# Error in fulfillment, cant access the entity values from google cloud platform

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-datastore, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to use fulfillment from the entity that I created Google Cloud but, even with no errors in the Deploy, when I test I have the error:

```
{
  "error": "Cannot read property 'Definicion' of undefined"
}
```

I attach the link with the image of the Cloud entity [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg1oi.png)

Also attach here the code.

```
'use strict';


const functions = require ('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require ('actions-on-google');
// instantiate the object
const datastore_enfermedades = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
// instantiate a datastore client
const datastore = datastore_enfermedades ();


const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';
const LOOKING_FOR_DISEASE_INTENT = 'InfoDisease';
const DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY = 'TypeDisease';


const app = dialogflow ();

app.intent (WELCOME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Hola! Si quieres puedo darte más información sobre alguna enfermedad, pregúntame!');
  });


app.intent (FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Ai, no te he entendido, ¿puedes repetirmelo por favor?');
  });

const disease1 = datastore.createQuery('Tabla de enfermedades').filter('Enfermedad', '=','artritis');
app.intent(LOOKING_FOR_DISEASE_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const disease_type = conv.parameters[DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
    if (disease_type == "artritis") {
        return datastore.runQuery(disease1).then(results => {
            conv.ask(results[0][1].Definicion);
        });
    } else {
        conv.ask("Puedes repetirlo por favor?");
    }
});


 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with handling it through fulfillment.

the issue appears to be that `results[0][1]` is undefined. Since the `RunQueryResponse` is in `results[0]` it suggests that you may need to examine `results[0]` to see what you're actually getting back and which values you intend to use.

You can look at that by calling `console.log(results[0])`.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me! 

I am kind of new with this whole thing, could you tell me how can I examine results[0]?

Thank you!!

Comment: Ok thank you, it was results[1], but now the error is

{
  "error": "Cannot read property 'simpleResponse' of undefined"
}

Do you know  where is simpleResponse? cause I cannot find it

Comment: And when I try ni actions on google the error is :
{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"0783191e-da98-40d2-9da4-1b3df7dd8ce7\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-01-14T09:44:07.188Z\",\"lang\":\"es-es\",\"result\":{},\"alternateResult\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 500...

Comment: Please don't try to put code or errors in comments - they are very difficult to read. Update your original question with the latest code and errors that you're seeing.